# How to change the place of an element in another element by javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to change the place of an element in another element

So this is what i have:

```
<div class="post-cont">
 <div class="post-thumail">
 </div>
<article>
  <div class="post-home">
    <div class="post-info">
     <div class="post-cont">
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

I want to change the place of the div with class `post-cont` before the div of class `post-thumail`

like this :

```
<div class="post-cont">
 <div class="post-cont">
 </div>
 <div class="post-thumail">
 </div>
<article>
  <div class="post-home">
    <div class="post-info">
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

I used the before() and append() jquery proprietaries and they don't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.insertBefore()`:

```
$('article .post-cont').insertBefore($('.post-thumail'));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wjxud43t/)**

**Note:** you have encorrect closing tag for `article`. it should be `</article>`. also make sure to close main div.

Comment: it doesn't work for me 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

Comment: @FancyTheme: check the fiddle. you had wrong markup as i noted already.

Comment: yes it's correct this is just a problem with writing

Answer (score 1):

Use this code...

```js
$('article .post-cont').insertBefore($('.post-thumail'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-cont">
 <div class="post-thumail">
   1st
 </div>
<article>
  <div class="post-home">
    <div class="post-info">
     <div class="post-cont">
       2nd
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</articale>
```